# Android Studio doesn't break on field access

Tags: android, android-studio

I have set to break on both read and write to a field, as shown below:
[image]

The problem is that the code never breaks when the field was access/modified when I know for a fact that the field was being accessed, and that breakpoints set in methods work as intended. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this: it's not a perfect solution, but a compromise one.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private boolean value = test();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (value) {
        // do sth.
        value = false;
    }
}

private boolean test() {
    return false;
}
}
```

create break point at `return false` line. But you may want to delete the extra code when the debugging is done.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I want to have a more permanent solution